# How can I reduce method lines to a loop?

Tags: python, odoo-12

how could I leave my code in a single loop? It limits me to do it because they have different def so I can't get to reduce the line of code.

```
  input_quantity= fields.Float(string="input_quantitya", compute="input_quantity")
  @api.one
  @api.depends ("detail_book_ids")
  def _stock_entry (self):
      sum = 0
      for detail_book in self.detail_book_ids:
          sum + = book_detail.quantity_debted
      self.input_quantity = sum

  merge_number= fields.Float(string="merge_number", compute="_stock_merma")    
  @api.one
  @api.depends ("detail_book_ids")
  def _stock_merma (self):
      sum = 0
      for detail_book in self.detail_book_ids:
          sum + = detail_book.quantity_merm
      self.merge_number = sum

  output_quantity= fields.Float(string="output_quantity", compute="_stock_output")
  @api.one
  @api.depends ("detail_book_ids")
  def _stock_output (self):
      sum = 0
      for detail_book in self.detail_book_ids:
          sum + = book_detail.quantity_to have
      self.output_quantity = sum
```

I need to do that because this is why I get the following error:
**RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.**

the field that calculates the stock is as follows

```
  stock= fields.Float(string="stock", compute="_stock")
  @api.one
  @api.depends('input_quantity','output_quantity','existencia','merge_numbe')
  def _stock(self):
      for rec in self:
          rec.stock = rec.existencia + (rec.input_quantity - (rec.output_quantity + rec.merge_numbe))
```

error in photo is :
[image: photoerror]

Comment: Please add the error log?

Comment: it does not show me more error than the one mentioned above, but it only happens when I select merge, because with the others it adds and subtracts the stock rather

Answer (score 1):

Hello Francisco González Mejías,

Optimize method in this way,Just called the **one method** for **all your field** with reduce line.

```
@api.multi
def _compute_common_funtion(self):
    self.input_quantity = sum(self.mapped('detail_book_ids').mapped('quantity_debted'))
    self.merge_number = sum(self.mapped('detail_book_ids').mapped('quantity_merm'))
    self.output_quantity = sum(self.mapped('detail_book_ids').mapped('quantity_to'))
```

Thanks

Comment: In the variables input_quantity, merge_number and output_quantity I have to put the same computed field?

Comment: I do this but in another computed variable where I calculate the stock does not subtract or add the stock of the products

Comment: @FranciscoGonzálezMejías yes for all three fields have one method execute.

Comment: @FranciscoGonzálezMejías what you face so far and what to achieve or face issue or error with your second comment not clear as much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as they did it in [sale module](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L39).

```
@api.depends("detail_book_ids")
def _amount_all(self):
    for stock_entry in self:
        input_quantity = merge_number = output_quantity = 0.0
        for detail_book in stock_entry.detail_book_ids:
            input_quantity += detail_book.quantity_debted
            merge_number += detail_book.quantity_merm
            output_quantity += detail_book.quantity_to_have

        # 1 database update
        stock_entry.update({
            'input_quantity': input_quantity,
            'merge_number': merge_number,
            'output_quantity': output_quantity,
        })
```

You can keep [@api.one](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/api.py#L219) like you did and remove the first loop in the `_compute_all` method then rename `stock_entry` to `self`.

**Edit**:

You have a field that depends on other computed fields and if you refer to the accounting invoice [_compute_amount](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L57) method, the way to do it is to use the same method and add the new depandeances in the decorator.

```
@api.one
@api.depends('detail_book_ids', 'existencia')
def _amount_all(self):
    input_quantity = merge_number = output_quantity = 0.0
    for detail_book in self.detail_book_ids:
        input_quantity += detail_book.quantity_debted
        merge_number += detail_book.quantity_merm
        output_quantity += detail_book.quantity_to_have

    self.input_quantity = input_quantity
    self.merge_number = merge_number
    self.output_quantity = output_quantity
    self.stock = self.existencia + (input_quantity - (output_quantity + merge_number))
```

Comment: I do this but in another computed variable where I calculate the stock does not subtract or add the stock of the products

Comment: Which variable?

Comment: add above the method I use to calculate the stock

Comment: Use the same method to compute `stock` filed, check my edit.

Comment: no case keeps getting RecursionError error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Show the error log or the code you suspect to be the origin of the error?

Comment: I suspect that another part of your code is causing the error